# Remove whitespace from table cell after image width reduction

Tags: html, css

This is probably really easy but I'm stuck trying to remove whitespace from a table cell when reducing the width of a nested image.

Eg I want to remove the whitespace in this example

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8qm61hny/

[image]

HTML:

```
    <div class="qtest">
        <div class="q_test">
            <div class="q_top">
            </div>
            <div class="q_test99">
                <table class="test_table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="q_p1">1st</td>
                            <td class="q_p2"><img class="q_p2_img" src="//www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/1_google_logo.jpg"></td>
                            <td class="q_name">Name1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="q_p1">1st</td>
                            <td class="q_p2"><img class="q_p2_img" src="//www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/1_google_logo.jpg"></td>
                            <td class="q_name">Name2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="q_p1">1st</td>
                            <td class="q_p2"><img class="q_p2_img" src="//www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/1_google_logo.jpg"></td>
                            <td class="q_name">Name3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.q_p2_img {
  width:60%;
}
```

I've tried various css display options but cannot find what I need to do this.

Comment: the width is percentage so it's based on the parent container. Saying 60% means 40% of whitespace. Use pixel value

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I think this is the correct answer so if you add it I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use percentage value because percentage value will get resolved **after** setting the parent width since we need a reference to resolve it. In your case, you will have 60% of the parent size and 40% of whitespace.

Use pixel value instead:

```css
.q_p2_img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="qtest">
  <div class="q_test">
    <div class="q_top">
    </div>
    <div class="q_test99">
      <table class="test_table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="q_p1">1st</td>
            <td class="q_p2"><img class="q_p2_img" src="//www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/1_google_logo.jpg"></td>
            <td class="q_name">Name1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="q_p1">1st</td>
            <td class="q_p2"><img class="q_p2_img" src="//www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/1_google_logo.jpg"></td>
            <td class="q_name">Name2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="q_p1">1st</td>
            <td class="q_p2"><img class="q_p2_img" src="//www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/1_google_logo.jpg"></td>
            <td class="q_name">Name3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this minimum table css for cross-browser and responsive `<table>` styling

html

```
<div class="tbl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>MoreData 21</td>
        <td>MoreData 22</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

css

```
.tbl {
  width: 100%; /* table width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.tbl * {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 0; /* remove gap */
}
thead, tbody, tr {
  width: inherit;
}
th, td {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
}
@media (max-width: 767.9px) {
  table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  }
}
```